# Leaflet : Bootstrap Toggle input for on/off layer is does not work properly

Tags: javascript, input, leaflet

I made a button to turn the layer on and off using Bootstrap Toggle. When all buttons are tried to be turned on and off, the data that appears is the same data. Each data should have 1 button according to the ID `lyrMosaicSP` or `lyrMosaicLS` on the input. You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/valensi/z0ugy5ar/22/

```js
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: osmAttrib
  });

var map = L.map('map').setView([0.4901708, 103.9593973], 9).addLayer(osm);

var data = $.getJSON(jsondata,
  function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.wiki_spbn.records.length; i++) {
      var layerVar = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][1];
      var layerUrl = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][3];
      var layerName = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][4];
      var layerFormat = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][5];
      var layerTransparent = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][6];
      var layerVersion = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][7];
      var layerAttribution = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][10];

      var layernya = L.tileLayer.wms('http://103.16.223.172:8080/geoserver/Prov_Kepri/wms', {
        layers: layerName,
        format: layerFormat,
        transparent: layerTransparent,
        version: layerVersion,
        attribution: layerVar
      });

      $('#' + layerVar).change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true)
          map.addLayer(layernya);
        else
          map.removeLayer(layernya);
      })
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="lyrMosaicSP" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-size="small" />lyrMosaicSP<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="lyrMosaicLS" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-size="small" />lyrMosaicLS
<div id="map"></div>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "wiki_spbn": {
    "columns": ["id", "var", "type", "url", "layers", "format", "transparent", "version", "minZoom", "maxZoom", "attribution"],
    "records": [
      [0, "lyrMosaicSP", "tile", "pustekdataUrl", "Mosaik SPOT 2014-2016 Prov Kepri", "image\/png", "true", "1.0.0", null, null, "Data Mosaik SPOT 2014-2016 Prov Kepri"],
      [1, "lyrMosaicLS", "wms", "pustekdataUrl", "Mosaik Landsat 2016-2017 Prov Kepri", "image\/png", "true", "1.0.0", null, null, "Data Mosaik Landsat 2016-2017 Prov Kepri"]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the variable in change method which scope has been finished. We have changed the code and update it at fiddle. Please check it: http://jsfiddle.net/z0ugy5ar/30/

```
    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: osmAttrib
        });

    var map = L.map('map').setView([0.4901708,103.9593973], 9).addLayer(osm);
var layerDatalyrMosaicSP = "";
var layerDatalyrMosaicLS = "";

var data = $.getJSON(jsondata, 
            function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.wiki_spbn.records.length; i++) {
                    var layerVar = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][1];
                    var layerUrl = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][3];
                    var layerName = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][4];
                    var layerFormat = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][5];
                    var layerTransparent = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][6];
                    var layerVersion = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][7];
                    var layerAttribution = data.wiki_spbn.records[i][10];

                   var layernya =  L.tileLayer.wms(wmslink,{
                        layers: layerName,
                        format: layerFormat,
                        transparent: layerTransparent,
                        version: layerVersion,                    
                        attribution:layerVar
                    }); 
                    if(layerVar == "lyrMosaicSP"){
                        layerDatalyrMosaicSP = layernya;
                    }
                    if(layerVar == "lyrMosaicLS"){
                        layerDatalyrMosaicLS = layernya;
                    }
                    $('#'+layerVar).change(function() {

                        if($(this).prop('checked')==true){
                                if($(this).attr("id") == "lyrMosaicSP"){

                              map.addLayer(layerDatalyrMosaicSP);
                            }else{
                                map.addLayer(layerDatalyrMosaicLS);
                            }

                        }else{
                                if($(this).attr("id") == "lyrMosaicSP"){

                              map.removeLayer(layerDatalyrMosaicSP);
                            }else{
                                map.removeLayer(layerDatalyrMosaicLS);
                            }

                        }
                    })

                    console.log(data.wiki_spbn.records[i][2]);
                }

            });
```

It is now working fine.

Comment: Hi, the code is working. But how to make lyrMosaicSP value dynamically base on database on code below "if(layerVar == "lyrMosaicSP"){
                        layerDatalyrMosaicSP = layernya;
                    }....." . If i add more than 2 layers, so i don't need to update the code continuously. And also for map.addLayer(layerDatalyrMosaicSP) and map.removeLayer(layerDatalyrMosaicSP)

Comment: Okay thank you, maybe i create new question for this issue.

Comment: Here's my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473036/leafletjs-how-to-make-iteration-is-dynamically